Possible 80s comedy/sitcom in English
I've been trying to find our what movie this clip is from:



It looks like a clip from the 80s. Could be older though.
The language was English, but the clip has been dubbed with music.
I'm not even sure whether it's a movie or a series.
Maybe someone can identify it?

Pretty sure that's Dabney Coleman. However, this might not be enough information for an ID question. Do you know anything else?

I'm afraid not. But thank you for at least some sort of information that I can use to do some more research!!

Maybe we can try to guess what year might this movie be from?

I think this is from the TV show "Buffalo Bill" (1983 - 1984). The male actor is Dabney Coleman and I believe the woman is Joanna Cassidy. This clip is from Season 1 Episode 11 "The Fan".




Thanks a bunch man! Didn't really expect someone to identify this. Again, thank you and Walt for your time and effort!

@Napoleon Wilson -- Thanks for the edit. Couldn't figure out why it wasn't working for me.
